# Why different DB Providers when using NCrunch and from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, ncrunch

I have this code:

```
            var v = new List<string>();
            using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = OleDbEnumerator.GetRootEnumerator())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    v.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", dataReader[0], dataReader[2]));
                }
            }
            var s = v.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

When running in debug in visual studio I get this:
[image]

when running in ncrunch I get this:

[image]

(I'm missing the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0)

Can anyone explain why the list of providers are different in visual studio debug and in ncrunch?

Comment: ACE is the Microsoft Office driver and the version depends on the Version of Office.  Version 12.0 is Office 2007,  ACE can come with Office or you can install the runtime version of ACE.  Many application come with the runtime version of ACE so if Office is not installed you can still use the interface.  ACE 12.0 is missing because Office is not installed.

Comment: There are two in the second list that don't appear in the first list as well. What platform is your project targeting? Given that Jet is in one list and not in the other and only exists in 32-bit form, I wonder whether your app is running in 64-bit mode while NCrunch runs in 32-bit mode. That said, I would have thought that having two ACE providers would require one to be 32-bit and the other 64-bit. Regardless, I'd suggest changing your target platform and see whether that changes the Debug list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns that it was, as suggested, related to 32bit vs 64bit builds.

The .csproj for the production code used
`<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>`
while the .csproj for the unit test used
`<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>`